# Working with MS SQL SERVER on PHP5.6

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

So I have a trouble here. Tried use mssql_connect() but interpeter says that function is undefinied. PHP.net advices [this](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php), but it suppports only older versions of PHP. Is it possible to connect to MS SQL Server database from PHP5.6? What extensions should I add, what functions can I use?

*Configuration details: localhost, Apache 2.4, PHP 5.6, OS Windows 8.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the MSSQL extension in the PHP.ini file.

If this extension is not installed, you need to install it in PHP.

Please tell your server details (OS/WebServer like apache nginx) so that I can explain in detail.

Comment: Generally I know how to add extensions to php.ini, but Microsoft released extensions only for PHP 2.2-2.4. I use Apache 2.4 on localhost

Comment: localhost? You are using Windows or Linux?

Comment: XAMPP or WAMP server? or you installed Apache and PHP on your own?

Comment: First you need to install this extension dll in PHP then enable the extension from php.ini

Comment: I installed manually PHP and Apache. What extension should I use if Microsoft gives only extensions for PHP5.3 and PHP5.4?

Comment: Use the PDO extension.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 <?php phpinfo();?>
```

to see what are available with your php installation. I advice you to use [PDO](http://a2znotes.blogspot.com/2014/09/introduction-to-pdo.html) instead of mysql_* functions. It supports several databases not only MSSQL or MySQL.

Comment: mysql_* functions are not used, mssql_* functions are used.

Comment: What do you mean by mysql_* are not used? One who uses mysql use mysql_* functions, mssql users may use mssql_* functions. What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: He asked in the question `Tried use mssql_connect()` not `mysql`

Comment: I only suggested to not use mysql_ or mssql_ functions. Instead use pdo which provides support for several databases.

Comment: Can u give me please the link where I can download the extension?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098 provides  The Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server provide connectivity to Microsoft SQL Server from PHP applications